# How to bypass Windows Vista from power up on dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot

I've been using the dual boot system with ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows Vista. I no longer want to use Windows but wish to keep all files. How do I make Ubuntu be the sole OS without wiping out everything I've done.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to bypass Vista at power up and go directly to Ubuntu without seeing that menu to select OS, you can easily do it by editing /etc/default/grub file.

[image]

Set the GRUB_TIMEOUT to 0 to skip the menu at startup. Optionally you may also want to set GRUB_DEFAULT to your desired entry in the GRUB menu if its not already set.